# Program received signal: “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

The writing of array data to  nsmarrHeader and nsmarrData work fine.
When I write those "2D" NSMutableArrays to the structure I get:  Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.

```
struct typeFile structFile;

[structFile.nsmarrHeader addObjectsFromArray: nsmarrHeader];
[structFile.nsmarrData addObjectsFromArray: nsmarrData];
```

this gets the same error:

```
[structFile.nsmarrHeader addObject: nsmarrHeader];
[structFile.nsmarrData addObject: nsmarrData];
```

So I am not sure what is wrong with writing to the structure or what I should do differently then?

thanks

Comment: are [structFile nsmarrHeader] and nsmarrHeader the same array? Same question for nsmarrData instances

Comment: Is there a purpose for using a C style struct to hold NSMutableArrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have objective-c objects as plain structure fields then they are not initialized by default and so in your code you're trying to send message to uninitialized object and thus get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error.

Before using your structure fields you should explicitly initialize them, but I think if that's possible better use objective-c objects instead of plain structs - that will make things much easier for you (e.g. memory management)